# Unable to use pip3 with sudo

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, pip

I am unable to use `pip3` as `sudo`. Currently if I don't use `sudo`, my computer assumes that I want to use `python3` but if I include `sudo` my computer assumes I want to use `python2`.

[image]

I want to be able to use both pip and pip3 with sudo.

If I attempt to install a library as both sudo and with pip3 I get an `ImportError`. Currently the way around this for me is to use the `--user` flag **without sudo**.

Is there a way I can use pip and pip3 with sudo? The only reason why I ask this is because I was looking at installation instructions for a library called `Tensorflow` [and they specifically include **sudo**](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#InstallingNativePip).

```
  sudo pip install -U tensorflow   # Python 2.7
  sudo pip3 install -U tensorflow  # Python 3.n
```

As I wanted to use tensorflow with python3, I used pip3 and --user without `sudo` to get around this. Is that an issue or is it bad practice to use `--user` ?

*EDIT: I am not sure why I received a negative rating - if there is an edit I need to make please comment.*

Comment: Don't use `sudo` with pip, period.  Where did you find those installation instructions? They should be changed.

Comment: Well I think Google should know what they're doing

Comment: @wim https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#InstallingNativePip

Comment: you seem to have a custom install of Python 3 for your local account, and your root account (used when you use `sudo`) doesn't have the environment variables to known about that local install. In a nutshell: in your case, don't use sudo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Currently if I don't use `sudo`, my computer assumes that I want to use `python3` but if I include `sudo` my computer assumes I want to use `python2`.  ... If I attempt to install a library as both `sudo` and with `pip3` I get an `ImportError`.

Yes, unfortunately if you followed [that guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#InstallingNativePip) then your system environment is likely now messed up in this way.

> Currently the way around this for me is to use the `--user` flag **without sudo**.

**Your way around is correct.** This is installing tensor flow for your user, not for the root user.

> The only reason why I ask this is because I was looking at installation instructions ... Is that an issue or is it bad practice to use `--user`?

It's not bad practice, it's good practice, and it's the guide that has the problem. In summary:

- Use `sudo` when **adding** or **removing** packages **with `apt-get`**.
- Do not use sudo to modify/upgrade a `pip` installation which was installed with `apt`.  The package manager does not like for his files to be moved from under his feet.
- If you want to upgrade pip to a version later than the one provided by your distributions repositories, do it in your home dir (`--user` or virtualenv) and don't mess with the system python/pip.

I've created [PR20927](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/20927/files) to hopefully improve this part of the guide.